# Subtract rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to subtract the rows with some logic in a dataframe like that:

[image]

I want to subtract the second row on the first rown in 'Qtd' variable. Then, the result would be like that:

[image]

I was looking for a pandas function like diff() but my dataframe had non-numeric variables and the first row always is NaN. Anyone has some tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) function can calculate the difference between consecutive rows in a pandas data frame.

For the trick to handle the NaN values, you can add `.fillna(df['Qtd'])` to fill values from the Qtd column as default to replace NaN values. Finally, if want to convert float diff value to an integer as shown in posted example then add `.astype(int)` to the end of the expression.

**Example:**

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"X":["Gold","Gold"], "Y": ["Dirty","Clean"],
                   "ID":[1,1], "Qtd": [11, 10],
                   "Day": [11, 11], "Month":[8,8],
                   "Year":[2021,2021]
                  })

df["Qtd"] = df["Qtd"].diff(-1).fillna(df['Qtd']).astype(int)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      X      Y  ID  Qtd  Day  Month  Year
0  Gold  Dirty   1    1   11      8  2021
1  Gold  Clean   1   10   11      8  2021
```

Comment: This worked very well for one day, I'll try to increase it for others day/month/year. This logic must be restrict just for some ID's, but your idea will help me a lot, thank you!